# Sonarqube github pull request decoration url incorrect

Tags: sonarqube

I have just about got sonarqube 9.5 developer edition working on our environment, with the pull request decoration on github, I find that the URL is wrong. What it ought to have is http:\sonarqubewebsrver.com<remainingurl> its replacing our sonarqube instance with localhost:9418 which appears to be a default value somewhere, I cant seem to find where to change it.

[image]

None of the URL's work, they will try to take you to http://localhost:9418/project/issues?id= what works is http://sonarqubeserver/project/issues?id=

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to update the Server base URL: Administration → General → Server base URL.
Then restart the sonarqube server.